# Basic CSS/HTML stacking up one DIV beneath another in a column

Tags: html, css

I realise this is so basic but cannot for the life of me work why I cannot get it working and have spent the last few hours trying everything

I need to the stack up DIVs so they form a big long column, one on top of the other. They are contained inside a JQuery scrollable DIV. I could absolute position all of the DIVS inside however there will be loads of them that change fairly regularly so would like a system where they automatically line if I have to insert a new one.

So I basically have one large Scrollable DIV. Inside this I have 2 other DIVs (#Release-Monsters  &  #Release-Insides) each containing 3 further DIVs. It is these 2 DIVs (#Release-Monsters  &  #Release-Insides) that I would like to stack on top of eachother to form a column. Once I have these 2 working I would to add about 50 or so more.

My CSS is this:

```
#All-Releases- {
    position:absolute;
    left:250px;
    top:210px;
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    z-index:3;
}
/* Used to control height of scrollable div*/
p.ex
{
height:600px;
width:100px;
}
 /* Vertical and horizontal scrollbar - one extra step required - add width of overview - overall width of scrolled content*/
#All-Releases- {
     width: 500px;
        }
#Release-Monsters {
    position:static;
    width:600px;
    height:322px;
    z-index:3;
    }
#Artwork-Monsters {
    position:absolute;
    left:19px;
    top:2px;
    width:284px;
    height:284px;
    z-index:3;
}
#Release-Title-Monsters {
    position:absolute;
    left:322px;
    top:0px;
    width:284px;
    height:284px;
    color: #CCC;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Century Gothic, Geneva, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: justify;
    z-index:3;
}
#Release-Info-Monsters {
    position:absolute;
    left:322px;
    top:25px;
    width:278px;
    height:284px;
    color: #CCC;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Century Gothic, Geneva, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: justify;
    z-index:3;
}
#Release-Insides {
    display:block;
    width:600px;
    height:322px;
    z-index:3;
    }
#Artwork-Insides {
    position:absolute;
    left:19px;
    top:2px;
    width:284px;
    height:284px;
    z-index:3;
}
#Release-Title-Insides {
    position:absolute;
    left:322px;
    top:0px;
    width:284px;
    height:284px;
    color: #CCC;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Century Gothic, Geneva, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: justify;
    z-index:3;
}
#Release-Info-Insides {
    position:absolute;
    left:322px;
    top:25px;
    width:278px;
    height:284px;
    color: #CCC;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Century Gothic, Geneva, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: justify;
    z-index:3;
}
```

and the HTML is this:

```
<div id="All-Releases-" class="default-skin demo">
<div id="Release-Monsters">
<div id="Artwork-Monsters"><img src="images/Release-Artwork/Monsters.jpg" width="284" height="284" /></div>
<div id="Release-Title-Monsters">MONSTERS</div>
<div id="Release-Info-Monsters">
1. Prologue<br />
2. Journey <br />
3. Candles <br />
4. Water <br />
5. Underwater <br />
6. Spores <br />
7. Campfire <br />
8. Dawn <br />
9. Attack <br />
10. Temple <br />
11. Encounter <br />
12. Monsters Theme 
    </div></div>
<div id="Release-Insides">
<div id="Artwork-Insides"><img src="images/Release-Artwork/Insides.jpg" width="284" height="284" /></div>
<div id="Release-Title-Monsters">INSIDES</div>
<div id="Release-Info-Insides">
1. The Wider Sun <br />
2. Vessel <br />
3. Insides <br />
4. Wire <br />
5. Colour Eye <br />
6. Light Through The Veins <br />
7. The Low Places <br />
8. Small Memory <br />
9. A Drifting Up <br />
10. Autumn Hill<br />
    </div></div>

<p class="ex"></p>

</div>

    <div id="All-Releases-" class="default-skin demo">
<div id="Release-Monsters">
<div id="Artwork-Monsters"><img src="images/Release-Artwork/Monsters.jpg" width="284" height="284" /></div>
<div id="Release-Title-Monsters">MONSTERS</div>
<div id="Release-Info-Monsters">
1. Prologue<br />
2. Journey <br />
3. Candles <br />
4. Water <br />
5. Underwater <br />
6. Spores <br />
7. Campfire <br />
8. Dawn <br />
9. Attack <br />
10. Temple <br />
11. Encounter <br />
12. Monsters Theme 
    </div></div>
<div id="Release-Insides">
<div id="Artwork-Insides"><img src="images/Release-Artwork/Insides.jpg" width="284" height="284" /></div>
<div id="Release-Title-Monsters">INSIDES</div>
<div id="Release-Info-Insides">
1. The Wider Sun <br />
2. Vessel <br />
3. Insides <br />
4. Wire <br />
5. Colour Eye <br />
6. Light Through The Veins <br />
7. The Low Places <br />
8. Small Memory <br />
9. A Drifting Up <br />
10. Autumn Hill<br />
    </div></div>

<p class="ex"></p>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(".demo").customScrollbar();
    });
</script
```

>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked over your HTML (not too bad except for list and `<br>`) and your CSS (overly complicated).

I cleaned things up a bit, you see the results at:

http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/42bgv/

**Major CSS Fixes**

Here is the CSS that I modified:

```
.All-Releases {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: 0px;
    width:600px;
    height: auto;
    color: #CCC;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Century Gothic, Geneva, sans-serif;
    outline: 2px dotted blue;
}
.Release-Monsters {
    position: relative;
    width:600px;
    height:322px;
    outline: 2px dotted gray;
}

...

.Release-Insides {
    position: relative;
    width:600px;
    height:322px;
    outline: 2px dotted gray;
}

...
```

Originally, you declared `absolute` position for `.All-Releases` which caused all the panels to overlap each other, not good.

For `Release-Monsters` and `Release-Insides`, use `position: relative` so that the absolutely positioned elements stay where you expect. (Note: there are simpler ways to do this without using absolute positioning).

Finally, use `class` instead of `id` since `id` values are suppose to be unique.

Also, take advantage of CSS cascade and keep the font and color declarations in the top level rule, `.All-Releases` in this example.

Comment: Comes with practice! Glad to help.  I would appreciate an up vote on this since it took some effort on my part to work through this.  Welcome to SO!  All the best.

Comment: It did just try and up vote this for you but it said I need a reputation of 15. If and when I do get up to 15 I will come back and up vote this for you. Thank you again, you have made my day!

Comment: No problem, I up voted your question so that will help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

Add a float property to each of the **s. For example:

```
#Artwork-Monsters {
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    left:19px;
    top:2px;
    width:284px;
    height:284px;
    z-index:3;
}
```

Comment: As soon as you set `position: absolute`, `float` is computed to `none`, for full explanation, see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Comment: Yes, that makes sense about absolute knocking out float. Still no idea where the spanner is in my code that is making these DIVs sit right on top of one another and not stacking underneath one another though.

Comment: I think I may have stumbled across the solution clear:left; in the main DIVs seems to do it

Answer (score 0):

I would change your html to have unordered lists to start with to get rid of all the br tags that you have and may be able to get it a little neater.

**JSFiddle**

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uk3BW/   <-- Doesn't have scroll bar

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uk3BW/1/ <-- Has scroll bar

**HTML**

```
<ul id="Release-Info-Monsters">
<li> Prologue </li> 
<li> Journey </li>
<li> Candles </li>
<li> Water </li>
<li> Underwater </li>
<li> Spores </li>
<li> Campfire </li>
<li> Dawn </li>
<li> Attack </li>
<li> Temple </li>
<li> Encounter </li>
<li> Monsters Theme </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul { 
 display:block;  
 background:#aeaeae;
 padding:10px;
 width: 250px;
 list-style:none;
}

li { 
    display:block;
    background:#eee; 
    padding: 10px 0; 
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}

li:last-child { 
margin: 0;
}

li { 
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;} 
li:hover { 
    background:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will do this if I can actually solve the main problem of not having the main DIVs sat on top of one another.

Comment: I think I may have stumbled across the solution clear:left; in the main DIVs seems to do it

Comment: you can also place a margin around the main div to keep them from stack up one on top of the other.  Also in your html you have the id of all releases as the main container for each div and in that you tell it to be at the top and left by a certain amount.  This is going to put them all ontop of each other with position absolute.  If it were relative it would place them based on their parent.